# Simple AJAX Get request is "pending"

Tags: ajax, node.js, jquery, express

I am trying to implement a simple AJAX GET request. This request tells the server to delete a document in a database. While I get confirmation from the server that the document is deleted, the Chrome Inspector shows that the request sits as "pending", eventually resulting in a server error.

What am I doing incorrectly?

**HTML**

```
<div class="delete-note">
    <a href="#"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.delete-note').click(function(e) {
  var url = '/docs/' + doc_id + '/note_destroy/' + note_id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    cache: false,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit: Including server-side code as well:

**Node/Express**

```
exports.note_destroy = function(req, res) {
  Doc.findOne({ doc_id : req.params.doc_id }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw (err);
    note_id = req.params.note_id;
    data.notes.id(note_id).remove();
    data.save(function(err) {
      if (err) throw (err);
      console.log('note ' + note_id + 'is removed.');
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: This is nit-picky, but if the request is to delete something, a POST or a DELETE request would be more appropriate than a GET.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is serverside, request not being closed and all ?

Comment: What/where do you see server confirmation?

Comment: can we use  e.preventDefault(); after the ajax is called ?\

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam I would think you could. It will just apply to the button click though and stop it from conducting its default action (whatever that may be). It shouldn't have any effect on the ajax call.

Comment: You are not sending any response to client in your server-side code. The browser shows request pending because it keeps waiting for a response.

Comment: To expand slightly on what @gbtimmon said, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) is a list of request methods and a brief definition of when each one is appropriate for use per the specification. For the full w3 specification visit [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) page.

Comment: Thanks everyone, especially @gbtimmon and @War10ck - I used `delete` for the ajax type and added `res.send(success);` to the route if the deletion was successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server-side function doesn't write any response, so the browser waits for it indefinitely.  Try writing a response, perhaps with some kind of status code that the client-side can check to tell whether the deletion worked.  Something like...

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
res.write(JSON.stringify({ status: OK }));
res.end();
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.  I was async'ly calling a webpage, which went off and did some lengthy processing, so was stuck as "Pending".  Now, I get the webpage to write something to response (including Response.End()), and launch a background Thread to do the time-consuming work.  No more "Pending" webpage problems !